# Div Tables in Html - including the clear floats issue

Tags: html, css-float, css-tables

I have been tinkering with the 'clear-floats' issue in html. It is basically needed for creating div based tables. (It's a good read, you should all read it: http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/).

I am doing things this way as I will ultimately be integrating some '@media' stuff in the css.

My basis idea is I am having a central strip (divMenuCenterContainer) which will have two columns in it (divMenuMiddleElement). Ultimately the divMenuMiddleElement will be stacked one on top the other for low @media screen widths. The trouble is I have not got that far yet. I cannot get the basic design working.

What I want is the divMenuCenterContainer centered in the middle of the screen. Within it are the two columns which at this stage will be next to each other, side by side.

THE FAULT: The left float (divMenuBlankLeftRight) does not appear at all when it has nothing it it (which is what I want). It only appears on a separate line above the two main columns (as opposed to on the left) when I put the letter 'A' in it.

WHAT I WANT: I want divMenuBlankLeftRight to appear on the left with nothing in it. Alternatively I want divMenuCenterContainer correctly centered without the need of divMenuBlankLeftRight.

OR: Is there a better way of doing this? Should I be using nth-child, and if so how do I get that working considering I need two columns in the middle centered (and ultimately stacked on top of each other for low width @media checks)?

This is what I have.

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 */
}
.divMenuContainer1
{
    border: solid 1px black;
    background: #0000FF;
}
.divMenuBlankLeftRight
{
    float: left;
    width: 19%;
    background: #FF0000;
}
.divMenuCenterContainer
{
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    background: #00FF00;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
.divMenuMiddleElement
{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: #00FF00;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="divMenuContainer1 clearfix">
    <!--<div style="width: 100%">-->
        <div class="divMenuBlankLeftRight">A</div>
        <div class="divMenuCenterContainer clearfix">
            <div class="divMenuMiddleElement">
                <p>Left Hand Central Column</p>
            </div>
            <div class="divMenuMiddleElement">
                <p>Right Hand Central Column</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divMenuBlankLeftRight"></div>
    <!--</div>-->
    <!--<div style="width: 100%">-->
        <div class="divMenuBlankLeftRight">A</div>
        <div class="divMenuCenterContainer clearfix">
            <div class="divMenuMiddleElement">
                <p>Left Hand Central Column 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="divMenuMiddleElement">
                <p>Right Hand Central Column 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divMenuBlankLeftRight"></div>
    <!--</div>-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for **WHAT I WANT**, I have added `margin:19%` and removed `float` from your `divMenuCenterContainer` container.

Please check result [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vasimkp/z7h5twx9/embedded/result/).

And take a look at [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasimkp/z7h5twx9/).

Thanks